# How to empty properly an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, object, nsmutablearray

I am trying to empty an NSMutableArray with the [myarray removeallobjects]; but I am getting error exc_bad_access. Is this the right way to empty the array? I tried to set it to nil but its not working either.
Actually what I am doing is filling the array with data and the user has the option to "refresh" the data and I want to empty the array before enter the refreshed data.
I cant post any code because is too big.

Comment: Can you add the part where you are adding the objects to the array?

Comment: [checkinArray addObject:checkinsA];
        [checkinsA.taggedID release];
        [checkinsA.taggedName release];
        [checkinsA release];
where checkinsA is a custom object. Also this command is in loop.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`-[NSMutableArray removeAllObjects]` is the correct way of emptying an `NSMutableArray`. You're most likely getting a crash because you're still using the objects that you removed somewhere, in your UI perhaps.

Comment: Or the object was over-released after adding to the array.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this snippet of code that you've provided in the comments,

```
[checkinArray addObject:checkinsA]; 
[checkinsA.taggedID release];
[checkinsA.taggedName release]; 
[checkinsA release];
```

`taggedID` and `taggedName` are properties of the `checkinsA` object. They should be released in the `dealloc` method only. The array does not retain the object tree. It retains the root object only. So there shouldn't be a release here. So knock out the two lines in the middle and make it

```
[checkinArray addObject:checkinsA]; 
[checkinsA release];
```

Comment: checkinsA.taggedID and taggedName are NSMutableArrays in the checkinsA. Also checkinsA is in a for loop.

Comment: for(NSDictionary *user in users) {
        Checkin *checkinsA = [[Checkin alloc] init];
        checkinsA.taggedName =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        checkinsA.taggedID =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...... [checkinArray addObject:checkinsA]; 
[checkinsA.taggedID release];
[checkinsA.taggedName release]; 
[checkinsA release];

Answer (score 0):

You are having a crash because your array is not existing anymore in memory.

I bet it is because you forgot to retain it (or released it too soon)

You probably created it using `[NSMutableArray array]` or `arrayWithObjects:` or some of those variants, or called `autorelease` after your `alloc`+`init`, whereas if it is an instance variable you should retain it until the objet is dealloc'd.

*Note that memory mgmt is a key part of iOS development. Be sure to know it perfectly (such as it becomes natural and you won't hesitate when to retain and when to release) before going further, it will avoid you a lot of trouble like this once you use it right.*

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *checkinArray; in my .h.     checkinArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in viewdidload and     [checkinArray release]; in dealloc(the last one is not the problem because its crashing even if I remove this line from dealloc). Do you see something wrong?